# BeautifulSoup original_encoding returns none

Tags: beautifulsoup, urlencode

I am trying to scrab below url which I actually achieved. However the content is unreadable because of Turkish characters and the page encoding returns None.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.digiturk.com.tr/yayin-akisi/api/kanal/liste/326'
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
print(soup.original_encoding)
```

Comment: Use chrome selenium driver and then translate it

Comment: What is the question ? Do you need to find encoding or just use the contents of soup?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want the text to be readable and the encoding to be utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

As BeautifulSoup is not able to identify encoding sometimes, try the below code to find encoding using  [*chardet*](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function)-

```
import urllib.request
rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
import chardet
chardet.detect(rawdata)
```

After finding the encoding, pass it to BeautifulSoup like this in your code-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser", from_encoding= "found_encoding")
```

Read more about BeautifulSoup encoding [here](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/10_encodings.html#encodings)

Comment: It says the encoding is the encoding is utf-8 but the output is not readable. I cant understand why. 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}

Comment: what do you mean by not readable? Do you want to translate the text? Cos the url is being parsed correctly

Comment: Parsing is ok but the text seems as below. It should be 21 Nisan 2020 Salı
 <h2>21 Nisan 2020 SalÄ±</h2>

Comment: "21 Nisan 2020 SalÄ±" is the original text as present on the URL provided in your question. Hence the same is parsed.

Comment: ok but the the text is not correct. it should be Salı. so the question is how I can make the output readable as Salı.